# Javascript maths is joining and not adding

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run some calculations but 1 of my vars are joining the numbers together instead of adding them, here is my code:

```
var pdfAround = parseFloat($('#direct_size_around').val());
    var qtyAround = parseFloat($('#direct_qty_around').val());
    var toothSize = parseFloat($('#direct_tooth_size').val());
    var gearNum = parseFloat($('#gearNum').val());
    var gearRepeat = parseFloat(toothSize * gearNum).toFixed(2);
    var gapAround = parseFloat((gearRepeat / qtyAround) - pdfAround).toFixed(3);
    var sizeAround = parseFloat(pdfAround + gapAround);
    var repeatPlus = parseFloat(gearRepeat + 0.5).toFixed(2);
    var repeatMinus = parseFloat(gearRepeat - 0.5).toFixed(2);
```

When I get the results all seem to be correct but the var sizeAround  is not, instead of 50 + 3.795 = 53.795 I am getting 503.975

I am not great with Javascript and believe I may be misunderstanding how to use parseFloat

Comment: This is because `toFixed()` returns a String instead of a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this call:

```
 parseFloat(pdfAround + gapAround);
```

concats strings `pdfAround`  and `gapAround` before parsing them. Try:

```
parseFloat(pdfAround ) + parseFloat(gapAround);
```

Comment: `pdfAround` is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `gapAround` is a string and hence is concatenated. You can try following

```
var sizeAround = pdfAround + parseFloat(gapAround);
```

Comment: `pdfAround` is not a string.

Comment: @explv - My bad - Incorrect copy. It was gapAround. I have corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your calls to `toFixed()`

`parseFloat()` parses a string and returns a floating point number

`toFixed()` converts a number to a string, with the specified number of decimals

So when you do:

```
var gapAround = parseFloat((gearRepeat / qtyAround) - pdfAround).toFixed(3);
```

You are converting the result of `parseFloat((gearRepeat / qtyAround) - pdfAround)` which is a float, to a **string**, and storing it in `gapAround`

This means that:

```
var sizeAround = parseFloat(pdfAround + gapAround);
```

Will be a **concatenation** operation, **not addition**, as `pdfAround` is a float, but `gapAround` is a string.

To fix this, all calls to `toFixed()` should be removed:

```
var pdfAround = parseFloat($('#direct_size_around').val());
var qtyAround = parseFloat($('#direct_qty_around').val());
var toothSize = parseFloat($('#direct_tooth_size').val());
var gearNum = parseFloat($('#gearNum').val());
var gearRepeat = toothSize * gearNum;
var gapAround = (gearRepeat / qtyAround) - pdfAround;
var sizeAround = pdfAround + gapAround;
var repeatPlus = gearRepeat + 0.5;
var repeatMinus = gearRepeat - 0.5;
```